# System.out.println doesn't work on client side

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

`System.out.println("blabla");` on client side doesn't show anything on console, but the same command on server side works correctly!

This is the code

```
System.out.println("blabla");

// Add auto on db
for(final AutoDTO i : auto){
    RonfService.addAuto(i, new AsyncCallback<AutoDTO>(){
    ....
    ....
}
```

`"blabla"` doesn't appear on consolle, but `System.out.println("add");` on `addAuto` method does

This is the code of `addAuto`:

```
@Override
public AutoDTO addAuto(AutoDTO autoDTO){
   System.out.println("add");
   Auto auto = new Auto(autoDTO);
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
   ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *client side*, probably when executing this in a scriptlet or in JavaScript (of course, through a scriptlet)?

Comment: How do you run Java code on the client side? And in *which* console do you expect the text to show up?

Comment: On my eclipse console, i'm using hibernate with eclipse for a school project

Comment: RonfService is on the server?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/407/yf87.png/

Comment: from where/how are you invoking the client?

Comment: private final RonfServiceAsync RonfService = GWT.create(RonfService.class);

Comment: You are seeing the server logs. If the client is also executed from eclipse, there will be two consoles in eclipse. check the client console

Comment: i've only 4 console avaible:
1)Android
2)RONF-Project - GWT compile
3)DDMS
4)Tomcat v7.0 blabla

1, 2, 3 are useless..

Tomcat v7.0..... is the only useful console

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using GWT. Are you running the application from within Eclipse (Dev Mode), or have you built the application and deployed it onto a server (Production Mode)? Calls to `System.out.println()` will work in Dev Mode, but not in Production Mode.

To use logging in Production Mode, have a read of the [GWT logging guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html).